# What and why do get Hit, Get, Ign, Release, Inrelease indicators, when we use sudo apt update

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-20.04

Please define me the terms and why do we get those indicators when we use sudo apt update command in ubuntu.

```
Get:1 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.9.0.131  InRelease [1,572 B]
Get:2 file:/var/nv-tensorrt-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.5.2-cuda-11.8  InRelease [1,575 B]
Hit:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Ign:9 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/6.0 InRelease
```